# Is it a Many to one or one to one relationship?

Tags: postgresql, data-structures, database-design, erd

I am struggling to wrap my head around this concept. Here is a pic of my ERD
[image: ERD]

Look at the tables 'Titles' and 'Employees'. Emp_title_id is a foreign key reference to title_id in Title. Now, there are same titles for multiple employees. So shouldn't that be a many-to-one relationship?
The argument against is that the two fields (emp_title_id in Employees and title_id in Title) have same set of values, so it is a one-to-one relationship.

Please let me know if I should think of it as set of values (one to one) or set of "cells" with different values (many to one)

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### One-to-many (1:n)

- An employee can have only **1** title.
- A title can be given to **n** employees.

(You have a 1:n relationship between employee and title, as an employee can have only one title. But you have established an m:n relationship between employee and department, as an employee can work in multiple departments. In the datamodel this can be seen from the existence of the bridge table dept_emp needed to provide m:n.)

Comment: Thanks. I am reading that as 1 to many.
I guess my confusion arises from the fact that for Titles and Employees the connection is same: Title_ID. Now even thought it has duplicate values in the employees table, distinct values still map to same value of Title ID. :s

Comment: Yep 1:n = one to many. As shown the question to ask are **1.** Can one x have only one or many y? and **2.** vice versa: Can one y have only one or many x? Thus you get 1:1 (very rare), 1:n (with one table's key column being referenced by a foreign key column in the other table), or m:n (with a bridge table consisting of both tables' keys). In your case: Can one employee have only one or many titles? Answer: Only one. Can one title have only one or many employees? Answer: Many. The relation is hence 1 to many.

Comment: This is the same concept as using a foreign key to reference a primary key.  It's the same concept, but a different level of abstraction.